# Short story about a man who wakes up in a future where only a small minority of people have interesting lives

Tags: story-identification

It turns out that the rest of the people plug into this minority and get to feel their experiences. Eventually he realises that his love interest's experience with him has been beamed into millions of people's heads. He is then told that he has to be fitted for broadcast too.

I read this a LONG time ago.

Comment: What is a "LONG" time? 1 year, 5 years, 50 years?

Comment: Sounds like a Spider Robinson story but he doesn't wake up in that future, a person from that future comes back to the present and seduces him while recording the experience for the enjoyment of future "mental voyeurs".

Comment: I'm thinking about "[The Girl Who Was Plugged In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Was_Plugged_In)" by James Tiptree, Jr., except the protagonist is female.

Comment: Sounds like the real world we actually live in, the cynical browser of the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange said. ;)